# Get Data in all Fields

Tags: javascript, html

Please help me in this issue
I want to fill all the fields with random data 
https://jsfiddle.net/omrmstg7/

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
var button = document.getElementById("my-button");
var input = document.getElementById("my-input");

var names = ["Henry", "Joseph", "Mark", "Michael"];

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    input.value = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
});
}//]]> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="my-button">Generate Random Names</button>
<input type="text" id="my-input" />
<input type="text" id="my-input" />
<input type="text" id="my-input" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `id` should be unique in same document.

Comment: getElementById only returns a single element. You can either give each input a unique id or use querySelectorAll to find all the input elements.

Comment: Want to get data in all fields but it is giving in just one field

Comment: how can use querySelectorAll in this script @jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your problem is that you want to fill *all* the inputs and it doesn't do that.

The problem is that `id` is reserved for unique elements.

So, if you change your HTML for `id` to be `class` instead, you would change your JavaScript to something like this:

```
var button = document.getElementById("my-button");
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("my-input");

var names = ["Henry", "Joseph", "Mark", "Michael"];

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function (input) {
        input.value = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
    });
});
```

Comment: couldn't help. Sir. changed but not showing any data.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Try it now, should work.

Comment: Working .. :) Bundle of thanks Sir .. (respect)

Answer (score 0):

Change the inputs to use a class instead of an id.

id values should be unique in HTML and `getElementById` only returns the first matching id.